# Can I access my Evernote Database server?

Tags: database, evernote

I have a free plan with Evernote, and I wanted to access my own database server on evernote cloud, to be able to perform SQL Queries.

Can I access my data on Evernote Database Cloud?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't access to the database directly. Alternatively, you can use APIs to interact with the service.
https://dev.evernote.com/